# init.gradle read properties from command line

Tags: java, properties, gradle, init

In my gradle script I've been able to successfully read properties like this:

`def environment = hasProperty('env') ? env : 'dev'`

Using this I can execute a build script like this:

`gradlew clean assemble -Penv=prod`

My issue comes in when I tried moving this to an `init.gradle` file. The file is recognized and I'm able to use other properties that I define in the script, however I'm not able to get any from the command line. How can I do this?

My `init.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        }
    }
    project.ext['nexusDomainName'] = 'https://example.com/nexus'
    project.ext['compileSdkVersion'] = 19
    project.ext['buildToolsVersion'] = "19"
    project.ext['minSdkVersion'] = 8
    project.ext['targetSdkVersion'] = 19

    project.ext['sourceCompatibility'] = '1.7'
    project.ext['targetCompatibility'] = '1.7'

    //hasProperty('release') is always false
    project.ext['archiveType'] = hasProperty('release') ? '' : '-SNAPSHOT'
    project.ext['archiveUrl'] = hasProperty('release') ? "$nexusDomainName/content/repositories/releases/" : "$nexusDomainName/content/repositories/snapshots/"


    // This buildEnv property won't read either
    project.ext['buildEnv'] = hasProperty('env') ? env : 'dev'
    println "prepping for $buildEnv"
    project.ext['archivesBaseNameSuffix'] = (project.ext['buildEnv'] == 'stage' || project.ext['buildEnv'] == 'dev') ? '-' + project.ext['buildEnv'] : ''

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'username'
                password 'password'
            }
            url "$nexusDomainName/content/groups/public/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-P` sets a *project* property, which isn't immediately available in an init script. (You can access projects and their properties from an init script, but that access will be deferred until the projects have been created.) However, using a *system* property (`-D`) should work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! (sorry for my delayed response)